# Fermat Kraitchik Factorization Method

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I am struggling to understand the following passage from my number theory book, i'm not sure i like his choice of language however it is the only book i can get a copy of for now. That being said I was wondering if someone could see if my understanding of this passage is OK. Would be much appreciated !

---

"Fermat's factorization scheme has at its heart the observation that the search for factors of an odd integer n (because powers of 2 are easily recognizable and may be removed at the outset, there is no loss in assuming that n is odd) is equivalent to obtaining integral solution x and y of the equation $n = x^2 - y^2$.

---

Does this passage mean that we assume that any integer $n$ that we are dealing with has already had the prime factor $2^k$ removed and therefore we can assume that the number N and the remaining prime factors are odd? This in turn enables us to use the fact that any odd integer can be represented as the difference of two squares.

Comment: A number divisible by $4$ is also the difference of two squares, but we can assume that $n$ is odd as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes it assumes that all factors of 2 are removed. In practice, for factoring a number we almost always (if not always) factor out small primes first. Hence you will not use Fermat's method until all even primes are removed.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much Yong Hao Ng. Out of curiousness does that mean in practise we would look to remove say $3,5,7..$ etc also?

Comment: Usually one will do trial division up till maybe a few thousand, maybe up till something like $2^{16}$. After that point, specialized methods like Elliptic Curve Method of factorization and $p+1,p-1$ takes over (more efficient). If that is still not enough you move on to quadratic sieve and general number field sieve.

Comment: Several other methods are also used either for simplicity (easy to code for example) or is competitive with what I mentioned earlier. Fermat's method here can be used after trial division and combined they form an easy to implement method for factoring moderate size integers.